# Connecting to an external MySQL server for legacy data on heroku using ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am building a new app that needs to do some importing of legacy data from an old app. The old apps database is mysql, which you obviously can't use on heroku, but I want to use postgres. Basically I am doing an ETL via activerecord.

Here's what I have so far:

```
# config/initializers/legacy_database.rb
LEGACY_DATABASE_URL = "mysql://myusername:#{ENV['LEGACY_DATABASE_PASSWORD']}@host/foo1008801154002"

# app/models/legacy.rb
class Legacy < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection LEGACY_DATABASE_URL
end

# app/models/legacy/user.rb
class Legacy::User < Legacy
  self.table_name = 'users'
end
```

If I am in the console and I run `Legacy::User.count` I get back the correct count. However if I try to do something like `Legacy::User.first` I get the following error:

```
Legacy::User Load (54.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
Mysql::Error: Table 'foo1008801154002.legacies' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `legacies`
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Table 'foo1008801154002.legacies' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `legacies`
```

I'm not sure why rails is adding on the `.legacies` to the table name, nor am I sure how to fix this. I figure it might be some setting in `Legacy.connection`

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was relatively simple. I had to add the line `self.abstract_class = true` to my Legacy Base class.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: if you have mysql2 gem in your bundle then need to put:

```
# config/initializers/legacy_database.rb
LEGACY_DATABASE_URL = "mysql2://myusername:#{ENV['LEGACY_DATABASE_PASSWORD']}@host/foo1008801154002"
```

(or load mysql gem in Gemfile)